# Google Kubernetes Cluster not autoscaling down

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

I have a GKE cluster with autoscaling enabled, and a single node pool. This node pool has a minimum of 1 node, and maximum of 5. When I have been testing the autoscaling of this cluster it has correctly scaled up (added a new node) when I added more replicas to my deployment. When I removed my deployment I would have expected it to scale down, but looking at the logs it is failing because it cannot evict the kube-dns deployment from the node:

```
reason: {
 messageId: "no.scale.down.node.pod.kube.system.unmovable"        
 parameters: [
  0: "kube-dns-7c976ddbdb-brpfq"         
 ]
}
```

kube-dns isn't being run as a daemonset, but I do not have any control over that as this is a managed cluster.

I am using Kubernetes 1.16.13-gke.1.

How can I make the cluster node pool scale down?

Comment: This behavior depend on the state of y our cluster. What have you installed on it? StatefulSet? DeamonSet? Other addon?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have only deployed a simple busybox deployment, with some requests and limits. I have no other deployments, and when I want it to test the scale down I completely remove this deployment. The kube-dns has been deployment by GKE and is not running as a daemon set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/issues/2377) github issue, where it specifies that you need to add a taint to the node pool. I have done this and then the node pool is auto scaled down to zero.

Documentation can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-taints).

Answer (score 10):

The autoscaler will not evict pods from the kube-system namespace unless they are a daemonset OR they have a PodDisruptionBudget.

For kube-dns, as well as kube-dns-autoscaler, and a few other GKE managed deployment in kube-dns, you need to add a poddisruptionbudget.

e.g:

```
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
  name: kube-dns-bbc
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kube-dns
```

Comment: This probably works on unmanaged clusters but it fails in Autopilot with:

`Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "configs/kube-dns-pdb.yaml": poddisruptionbudgets.policy is forbidden: User "my-email@gmail.com" cannot create resource "poddisruptionbudgets" in API group "policy" in the namespace "kube-system": GKE Warden authz [denied by managed-namespaces-limitation]: the namespace "kube-system" is managed and the request's verb "create" is denied`